# Ignore NA while using mapply

Tags: r, na, mapply, na.rm

I have the following dataset:

```
longitude   latitude
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
-73.77384042    40.64582098
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
```

I am using the below code for converting the lat & long to get the location using the below code:

```
tweets1.df$textAddress <- mapply(FUN = function(lon, lat) revgeocode(c(lon, lat)), tweets1.df$longitude, tweets1.df$latitude)
```

But I am getting the following error:  `Error: is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 2 is not TRUE`

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Look at `str`; are your variables numeric? Also, you could probably just do `apply(tweets1.df, 1, revgeocode)`, but you need to specify packages so your question is [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). If it really is the `NA`s, wrap the vectors you pass (`tweets.df$*`) in `na.omit` or construct an `ifelse`.

Comment: e.g. `apply(df, 1, function(x){ifelse(any(is.na(x)), NA, revgeocode(x))})`

Comment: @alistaire: The `revgeocode` takes both the long and lat as inputs. Using your example. I am not able to figure out how can I do it. Could you please tell me with `x` & `y` variable

Comment: `x` will be a vector of both variables, which is what the function needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
options(digits=16)
indices <- which(complete.cases(tweets1.df[,1:2]))
tweets1.df$textAddress <- NA
tweets1.df[indices,]$textAddress <- mapply(FUN = function(lon, lat) 
                    revgeocode(c(lon, lat)), 
                    tweets1.df[indices,]$longitude, 
                    tweets1.df[indices,]$latitude)

tweets1.df


longitude    latitude                        textAddress
1            NA          NA                               <NA>
2            NA          NA                               <NA>
3            NA          NA                               <NA>
4            NA          NA                               <NA>
5  -73.77384042 40.64582098 Terminal 5, Jamaica, NY 11430, USA
6            NA          NA                               <NA>
7            NA          NA                               <NA>
8            NA          NA                               <NA>
9            NA          NA                               <NA>
10           NA          NA                               <NA>
```

you can try this too, a little modification of what suggested in the comments:

```
tweets1.df$textAddress <- apply(tweets1.df, 1, function(x){print(x);ifelse(any(is.na(x)), NA, revgeocode(x))})
```

Comment: do you have the exactly same data? do you have columns 1 & 2 as lat & lon? can you first try on the sample you provided and see it working?

Comment: The first column is long and the second column is lat.

Comment: Also the actual dataset is huge..containing 10000 rows. Can that be the reason.

Comment: i included the output generated from your sample data, did you want something like that?

Comment: should not be the reason

Comment: Can you please suggest any other way of doing this??

Comment: My dataset contains lat long with 8 digits after decimal, but you output contains only 3 digits after the decimal...how is that??

Comment: I got it with this extra line of code :
`tw1.df <- data.frame(lapply(tw1.df, function(x) round(as.numeric(x), 4)))`
and after that your code worked...Thanks for you help

Comment: great, some issues with numeric precision was there.